# Can't add module dependencies Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, opencv

Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 2

I’m going through the [OpenCV & Android beginners tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/df8/tutorial_dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html)

I got to section 7 Add the module to the project:

```
Click File → Project structure… → Dependencies → All modules → + (Add Dependency button) → Module dependency
```

But there is no option to add a module dependency as shown in the tutorial. There is only the first two options.

[image]

So, `import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;` can’t be resolved.

How do I add OpenCV as a dependency?

Comment: oh wow, they updated the tutorial for v4.9! that's awesome! if you have any issues, feel free to jump into the github issues for opencv and let them know. perhaps there's a corresponding (merged) PR or an existing issue where the PR was prepared.

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/cant-add-opencv-module-to-dependencies/16503